# Validation failed: Datafile translation missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a little rake task.  It fetches an XML file from an FTP server and stores it as a paperclip attachment to a record.

It has all of a sudden stopped working with an error:

```
Validation failed: Datafile translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.run.attributes.datafile.spoofed_media_type
```

The error looks like it thinks the file isn't XML, but it definitely is & uploading the same file to the model through active admin works fine. It also seems to be something to do with translations. I don't have any, its an app in english with no translation plans.

How can i fix the error and save the file?

I'm using rails 4.0 and gem "paperclip", "~> 4.1.0"

```
    tmp = Tempfile.new('foo')
    ftp.gettextfile(file_name, tmp.path)
    run = Run.new
    run.type_of_data = "Rider Updates"
    run.file_name = File.basename(file_name)
    run.datafile = tmp
    run.save!
```

Comment: think this is already an issue on paperclips repo: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1429